# How to create a python method

Tags: python

I've gone through a couple of questions for an hour or so but can't find why my code won't work. Here is the code. I have tried changing the body to something like `name.self` and it returns the same error. This question has been asked a couple of times but I've unfortunately not found any solution.

```
class Employees(object):
    def _init_(self,name,rate,hours):
        self.name=name
        self.rate=rate
        self.hours=hours
        staff=Employees("Wayne",20,8,5)
print(staff.name,staff.rate,staff.hours)
```

To which I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'staff' is not defined
```

Comment: The constructor needs to be named `__init__` (note the double underscores)

Comment: Also the `print` call needs to be at an indentation level where `staff` is actually defined, which is what the error is trying to tell you.

Comment: How do I make these underscores without using onscreen keyboard?

Comment: Also, the indentation is all messed up. As it is now, you are creating a new `Employee` within the contructor of `Employee`, leading to an infinite recursion, if the constructor were ever to be called (which for the same reason right now it is not)

Comment: When exactly do you expect that `print` to be executed? The indentation is wrong for it to be part of the method, and `staff` is local to the body of `__init__`, not available outside the function.

Comment: @NelsonGon: By writing two underscores, isntead of just one.

Comment: I made it part of the method as a test. Thought it was the cause of the error.

Comment: In case this was confusing, those are not special "double-width underscores" but just two regular underscores.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructor needs to be named `__init__` (note the double underscores)
Furthermore, your indentation cannot work here. I assume you want something like this:

```
class Employees(object):
  def __init__(self,name,rate,hours):
    self.name=name
    self.rate=rate
    self.hours=hours

staff = Employees("Wayne",20,8)
print(staff.name,staff.rate,staff.hours)
```

Comment: What's the keyboard shortcut to this character, sorry?

Comment: @NelsonGon all these are typable without a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Exactly, no shortcuts involved.

Comment: How do I do it?, sorry I'm a novice.

Comment: @NelsonGon Are you confusing the two underscores with a special character? Just type two of these: `_`

Comment: Um, just type all individual characters into a file. Note that all "blocks" (i.e. in the constructor) must have the same indentation to be executed in the same block.

Comment: Got it. Thanks! Python community sure is super active,woooow!

Comment: Want to close the question but that will take a few more minutes.

Comment: @NelsonGon why does it need to be closed? Questions aren't closed just because of a few downvotes.

Comment: I need to accept an answer to possibly stop people from posting more answers as I've resolved the issue.

Comment: @NelsonGon then just accept an answer. Questions with an accepted answer rarely get new answers.

Comment: A few more seconds and I can do that.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have the init with underscores like below, also to make it easier please add indentation to the code on questions.

```
class Employees(object):
    def __init__(self, name, rate, hours):
        self.name=name
        self.rate=rate
        self.hours=hours
staff = Employees("Wayne",20,8,5)
print(staff.name,staff.rate,staff.hours)
```

You will get an `__init__() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given` TypeError because you have 4 arguments in `Employees("Wayne",20,8,5)`.

For rate, did you mean to do `Employees("Wayne",20.8,5)`

Answer (score 3):

```
 class Employee(object):
        def __init__(self, name, rate, hours):
            self.name = name
            self.rate = rate
            self.hours = hours

 staff = Employee("Wayne", 20, 8)
 print(staff.name, staff.rate, staff.hours)
```

Several remarks:

1. The initializer method is called `__init__()`, not `_init_()`
2. Class name should normally be a singular noun, because a single instance typically corresponds to a single (real-world) object
3. Indentation matters

Comment: as mentioned in another answer your code will generate a TypeError, because `__init__ take 4 arguments but 5 given`

Comment: Well, I copied OPs code, and he provides too many arguments. I'll adapt it.

Comment: Right, will fix.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question. But you need a complete **init** for instantiation. Then, I guess "Wayne" is an instance of your object (see below).

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, rate, hours):
        self.name = name
        self.rate = rate
        self.hours = hours

wayne = Employee("Wayne", 20, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a `TypeError` because `staff` is being defined *within* the `_init_` method, making it a local variable. Also, `_init_` is not automatically called when a new object is created, `__init__` is called. Finally, you are passing too many arguments to the it. Change it to this:

```
class Employees(object):
    def __init__(self,name,rate,hours): #Note the two underscores
        self.name=name
        self.rate=rate
        self.hours=hours

staff = Employees("Wayne",20,8) #Now in the global scope
print(staff.name,staff.rate,staff.hours)
```